# Storybook, import CSS file into MDX documentation file

Tags: css, storybook

I'm styling a series of documentation pages in MDX. I can use the  tags smoothly but I also need to import some font rules that are contained in an external CSS file. Any idea about how to do it?

Right now the page is using a random "Nunito Sans" font that I can't find anywhere.

My MDX:

```
import { Meta } from "@storybook/addon-docs"


<Meta title="QuickStart/Changelog" />

<style>
    {`

* {
  font: inherit;
}
  
.text-style-square {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.text-style-wrapper {
  margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

.text-style-wrapper:first-child {
margin-top: 0;
}

.text-style-wrapper:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.section-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
`}
</style>

<img src="./img/changelog-banner.png" className="banner pb-10" />

<h1>OVERVIEW</h1>

Welcome to the Design System changelog, where we keep track of all updates and improvements to our design system.

<div className="section-wrapper">
    <h3>1.116.0 (2023-04-09)</h3>
    <p>#1201 Fix hide border bug in expand collapse (@hadasfa)</p>

    <h3>1.116.0 (2023-04-09)</h3>
    <p>#1201 Fix hide border bug in expand collapse (@hadasfa)</p>

    <h3>1.116.0 (2023-04-09)</h3>
    <p>#1201 Fix hide border bug in expand collapse (@hadasfa)</p>

    <h3>1.115.1 (2023-04-04)</h3>
    <p>Fix text field and search disabled appearance (@hadasfa)</p>

    <h3>1.115.1 (2023-04-04)</h3>
    <p>Fix text field and search disabled appearance (@hadasfa)</p>

    <h3>1.115.1 (2023-04-04)</h3>
    <p>Fix text field and search disabled appearance (@hadasfa)</p>

    <h3>1.115.1 (2023-04-04)</h3>
    <p>Fix text field and search disabled appearance (@hadasfa)</p>

</div>
```